# Ext.grid.column.Widget add remove widget or show hide widget

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, widget

New to Ext JS and 5.0.1 is new, did not find much help.

Wanted to know is there any way to control the visibility or add/remove of Widget in Ext.grid.column.Widget column ? Normally would be using renderer function of simple column to add remove widget like button. How to do it with this new feature.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?290124

Comment: Thanks Man , It solved the problem.... You can add this solution as Answer.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli please create a answer with the snippet code from forum so I mark it correct. So the people refer to the same this site only for solution.